# React: Changing the background color of TreeSelect (antD component)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd

I'm trying to change the background color of a TreeSelect component of [antD](https://ant.design/components/input/#header)

tried these ways:

```
 // const bgColor = element.Style !== undefined && element.Style === Constants.StyleModes.MAJOR ?
                    //     "#CFECF5" : "white" //TODO - didn't override the ant-select-selector

                    // const listStyle = element.Style !== undefined && element.Style === Constants.StyleModes.MAJOR ?
                    //     "small-font styled-element" : "small-font"
                    elements.push(
                        <td className="view-cell" align="left">
                            {element.Name}
                            <br/>
                            <TreeSelect
                                className="small-font"
                                style={{ width: '100%', fontSize: 'small' /*, backgroundColor: bgColor*/}}
```

but it's not taking effect;
If I add "!important" to bgColor const, the style is not shown in the element when inspecting it but If I remove the important its shown there but not taking effect to cause the antD style "ant-select-selector" is stronger and overriding it:

[image]

If I add this style to my css it will affect all lists and I want to style only specific ones based on some logic:

```
 .ant-select-selector {
    background-color: #CFECF5 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (you can see the right selector in DevTools):

```
.treeSelect.ant-select-single:not(.ant-select-customize-input)
  .ant-select-selector {
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

<TreeSelect className="treeSelect"/>
```

[image: Edit Basic - Ant Design Demo]

Comment: Thanks Dennis. It's affecting the style of all lists and not the only one that I'm interested in!

Comment: Not sure what you mean, thats the value according to your image.

Comment: I mean that i have more than one list in my form, and I don't want to affect them all... only some. The style that you gave is affecting all of them

Comment: Why should it? It affects only the ones with the `className="treeSelect"`, see updated sandbox which shows there is no such effect.

Comment: Ignore it, my bad (forgot to remove the old style). working perfectly thanks a lot